CSS animation starts delayed
I have multiple background images, which should change by animation. Here is a MWE:


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  animation: fade 16s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

img:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

img:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

img:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: 8s;
}

img:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: 12s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <img alt="01" src="https://i.imgur.com/CzXTtJV.jpg">
  <img alt="03" src="https://i.imgur.com/OB0y6MR.jpg">
  <img alt="04" src="https://i.imgur.com/OnwEDW3.jpg">
  <img alt="05" src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3075/3168662394_7d7103de7d_z_d.jpg">
</div>



It works fine, but somehow the image fading starts delayed, in this case only after 16s the first image is fading out and the second image is fading in. After this initial delay, the timing seems to be correct.
How can I fix this?

The images are all stacked on top of each other, the latest one in your source code being on the very top. It has an opacity of 1, which you only start decreasing with your animation, after a 12 second delay. But until you start decreasing the opacity, you will of course not see anything of the images below this one.

How about using negative delays? Subtract 16 seconds from the delays you currently have on each element, and see if you like how it behaves then, any better.

Explanation

Animation Delays : By setting negative delays, the animations start partway through their cycle, which means the fading effect begins almost immediately when the page loads. The delays are adjusted so that each subsequent image starts its animation slightly later than the previous one, creating a continuous fading effect.

Animation Duration : The total duration of the animation is reduced to 8 seconds. This means each image will cycle through its fade in and fade out in 8 seconds instead of 16 seconds.

Keyframes : Simplified to make the image fully visible at both the start and end of the animation, with a fade to zero opacity in the middle.


* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .container {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }

    .overlay {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 10;
    }

    img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        object-fit: cover;
        animation: fade 8s ease-in-out infinite;
    }

    /* Need to update */

    img:nth-of-type(1){
        animation-delay: -6s;
    }
    img:nth-of-type(2){
        animation-delay: -4s;
    }
    img:nth-of-type(3){
        animation-delay: -2s;
    }
    img:nth-of-type(4){
        animation-delay: 0s;
    }
    
    /* Better Practice */

    @keyframes fade {
        0%, 100% {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        50% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }

<div class="container">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <img alt="01" src="https://i.imgur.com/CzXTtJV.jpg">
    <img alt="03" src="https://i.imgur.com/OB0y6MR.jpg">
    <img alt="04" src="https://i.imgur.com/OnwEDW3.jpg">
    <img alt="05" src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3075/3168662394_7d7103de7d_z_d.jpg">
</div>


That does what I was expecting! Note: The suggested @keyframes fade chances don't do what the "old" ones did.

The fade animation time is the todal duration, it should be the time all images need to transit once through the animation.

animation running without delay


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  animation: fade 16s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

img:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-delay: -16s;
}

img:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: -12s;
}

img:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: -8s;
}

img:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: -4s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <img alt="01" src="https://i.imgur.com/CzXTtJV.jpg">
  <img alt="03" src="https://i.imgur.com/OB0y6MR.jpg">
  <img alt="04" src="https://i.imgur.com/OnwEDW3.jpg">
  <img alt="05" src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3075/3168662394_7d7103de7d_z_d.jpg">
</div>



